# OK button not working in vaadin

Tags: java, spring-mvc, onclick, vaadin

I have a sub window with one text field and two buttons OK and Cancel. When I click on OK button, nothing's happening. I don't understand what mistake I am making. Can someone help me with this. Also I would like to know how should I put multiple email addresses in one text field separated by semi colon.

Here is my code

**Update: Hi everyone, I solved the issue. Thank you**

```
package com.xitee.ccpt.ui.window;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

import com.vaadin.data.Binder;
import com.vaadin.data.HasValue.ValueChangeEvent;
import com.vaadin.data.validator.EmailValidator;
import com.vaadin.ui.FormLayout;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.xitee.ccpt.entity.Person;
import com.xitee.ccpt.entity.Phone;

public class PersonWindow extends DialogWindow<Person>{
     private static final String WINDOW_WIDTH = "400px";
     private static final String WINDOW_HEIGHT = "270px";
     private static final String ENTER_VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS = "Enter valid email address";

     private final FormLayout mainLayout;

     private final TextField efield;

     private Person email;
     private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonWindow.class);

    public PersonWindow(String title, DialogWindowListener<Person> listener ) {
     this (title, listener,"");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public PersonWindow(String title, DialogWindowListener<Person> listener, String type)
    {
        super(title, listener, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        LOGGER.info("Creating dialog window: Email window");



        mainLayout = new FormLayout();


        efield = new TextField("Email:");


        mainLayout.addComponent(efield);

        init(mainLayout);

        doFieldValidations();

    }

    Binder<Person> binder = new Binder<>(Person.class);

    @Override
    protected void doFieldValidations() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        binder.forField(efield).withValidator(new EmailValidator(ENTER_VALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS));



    }

     public void setEmail(Person email)
        {
            LOGGER.info("Loading Email  " + email.getPersonId() + " into email dialog window");

            efield.setValue(email.getEmail());
            this.email = email;
        }

    @Override
    protected boolean confirmed() {

        if (!isEmpty())
        {
            if (isValid())
            {
                if (email == null)
                {
                    email = new Person();
                }

                email.setEmail(efield.getValue());


                listener.dialogConfirmed(email);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isEmpty() {

        boolean ret = true;
        if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(efield.getValue()))
        {
            ret = false;
        }
        return ret;
    }


    @Override
    protected boolean isValid() {
        return false;

}

}
```

Code for OK Button

```
Button okButton = new Button("OK");
        okButton.addClickListener(new ClickListener()
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 2387863967859745591L;
            @Override
            public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event)
            {
                if (confirmed())
                {
                    close();
                }
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.addComponents(cancelButton, okButton);
    }
```

Comment: Double check this. Your isValid() returns always false, so probably confirmed() is always false too and hence close() is newer called.

Comment: @TatuLund I didn't write any code in validation method because I am getting error for isValid() method as undefined. The method is deprecated. Is there other way I can validate the field ?

Comment: If you get an error, then please state that in the question and not down here in the comments.

Comment: Which IsValid method is undefined or deprecated?